# Use methods or closures for grails webflow controllers?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Evidently **since grails 2.0 methods are recommended above closures for controller actions**. I've been converting them in an application I'm maintaining when I touch them. It should **save some permgen** space. I've come across a webflow controller now and when I convert them to methods **([as per the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Plug-ins/web%20flow.html))**  grails returns the 404 page when you navigate to the url defined by the method.

Is this an inconsistency or am I doing something idiotic?

```
        def uploadFlow() {
        onStart {
            // do stuff
        }
```

Comment: Please provide more information about 1. your webflow status and related code 2. what exactly happened when you mention 'it doesn't work'

Comment: what do you mean by webflow status? the controller action method never gets exercised so the contents are irrelevant

Comment: You're not alone with this issue! My project's action methods have just stopped working. Been on grails 2.0.1, still am from what I can tell, but I now get 404 errors. Changing to closures resolves the problems, but I shouldn't have to do that as I haven't downgraded my project, plus too many actions to change. I'm stumped as to what has changed to stop methods from working, it certainly wasn't anything intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that webflow definitions have to be closures, not methods.

Its mentioned here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7958

The entry is 18 months old, but I believe it is still the case (I've come across this problem too, whilst attempting to change all my Controller closures to methods).